# Can I change the password for vmc tunnel?

Tags: cloud-foundry

It's too long for MongoExplorer.  For some reason MongoExplorer set the maximum password length to 20.  The one generated by mvc tunnel doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't as this is actually the credentials generated for your service (not only for the tunnel feature). Maybe you can pass the password to MongoExplorer in another way (maybe command line argument?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the password is generated so you cannot change it. I would raise a defect/bug against MongoExplorer (I just checked, and the site says that development is currently suspended). FWIW on the Mac I use MongoHub as a GUI, and that works fine with a vmc tunnel.